# How to get data from array in PHP?

Tags: php

Can you help me ..
I have the following array

```
    Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 0930
            [1] => movie name 1
            [2] => 6,00
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1130
            [1] => movie name 2
            [2] => 5,00
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1345
            [1] => movie name 3
            [2] => 4,00
        )
..........
...etc...
........
```

My question is how to bring the results so

```
     <div id="movies">
            <div class="movie1">
                <div class="time">0930</div>
                <div class="name">movie name</div>
                <div class="price">6,00</div>
            </div>
            <div class="movie2">
                <div class="time">1130</div>
                <div class="name">movie name</div>
                <div class="price">5,00</div>
            </div>
 ............
    ...etc......
    ............
        </div>
```

Try several ways but were unsuccessful.
I would be very grateful if you help me ...!

Comment: What are these several ways you speak of?

Comment: You may want to include examples of what you have tried, and why they have not worked.

Comment: Forget two loops, one loop will handle it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<div id="movies">
  <?php 
    foreach($yourArray as $idx => $movie) {
      ?>
      <div class="movie<?php echo ($idx+1); ?>">
        <div class="time"><?php echo $movie[0]; ?></div>
        <div class="name"><?php echo $movie[1]; ?></div>
        <div class="price"><?php echo $movie[2]; ?></div>
      </div>
      <?php
     }
   ?> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Give this a whirl

```
<?php

$counter = 1;
foreach($array1 as $array2){
    print '
        <div class="movie'.$counter.'">
                <div class="time">'.$array2[0].'</div>
            <div class="name">'.$array2[1].'</div>
            <div class="price">'.$array2[2].'</div>
        </div>
';
$counter++;
}
```